# Reading multiple txt files into data frames and merging them into one

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I can't make this work with the information I'm finding.

I have many .txt files in a folder, each of them containing data from one subject. The files have identical columns, but the number of rows for each file varies. In addition, the column headers only start in row 9. What I want to do is

1. import the .txt files into RStudio in one go while skipping the first 8 rows, and
2. merging them all together into one data frame by their columns, so that the final data frame is a data set containing the data from all subjects in long format.

I managed to do 1 (I think) using the easycsv package and the following code:

```
fread_folder(directory = "C:/Users/path/to/my/files",
             extension = "TXT",
             sep = "auto",
             nrows = -1L,
             header = "auto",
             na.strings = "NA",
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             verbose=getOption("datatable.verbose"),
             skip = 8L,
             drop = NULL,
             colClasses = NULL,
             integer64=getOption("datatable.integer64"),# default:"integer64"
             dec = if (sep!=".") "." else ",",
             check.names = FALSE,
             encoding = "unknown",
             quote = "\"",
             strip.white = TRUE,
             fill = FALSE,
             blank.lines.skip = FALSE,
             key = NULL,
             Names=NULL,
             prefix=NULL,
             showProgress = interactive(),
             data.table=FALSE
)
```

That worked, however now my problem is that the data frames have been named after the very long path to my files and obviously after the txt files (without the 7 though). So they are very long and unwieldy and contain characters that they probably shouldn't, such as spaces.

So now I'm having trouble merging the data frames into one, because I don't know how else to refer to the data frames other than the default names that have been given to them, or how to rename them, or how to specify how the data frames should be named when importing them in the first place.

Comment: It would be great to provide some sample/example data that people could use to try and help you with.

Comment: Lacking anything else, I'd probably start with `do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(path=..., pattern=..., full.names=TRUE), read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work well. However, without sample data or a more clear description of what you want it's hard to know for certain if this if what you are looking to accomplish.

```
#set working directory
setwd("C:/Users/path/to/my/files")

#read in all .txt files but skip the first 8 rows
Data.in <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$"),read.csv,header=T,skip=8)  

#combines all of the tables by column into one 
Data.in <- do.call(rbind,Data.in)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work - however, the code seems to assume my files have only one column, but it's actually 12 (separated by tabs/blank space). So the first 8 rows are just an analysis log, then row 9 has the column names and from row 10 on comes the data. I tried including a sep argument but I just got "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names".

Comment: The code was assuming your files were comma separated, you could edit the second line to the following (I haven't tested this yet so it's possible I've made a small mistake)   `Data.in <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$"),read.table,sep="\t",header=T,skip=8)` That should read in tab separated tables. if your data is space seperated you can switch `"\t"` to `" "`

Answer (score 1):

The code below looks for what files are in your directory, uses those names to **get** the file as a variable, and then uses **rbindlist** to combined the tables into a single table.  Hope that helps.  It assumes each .csv or .txt file in the directory has been pulled into the current environment as a separate data.table.

```
for (x in (list.files(directory))) {

    # Remove the .txt extension from the filename to get the table name
    if (grepl(".txt",x)) {
        x = gsub(".txt","",x) 
    }

    thisTable <- get(x) # use "get" to pull in the string as a variable

    # now just combined into a single dataframe
    if (exists("combined")) {
        combined = rbindlist(list(combined,thisTable))
    } else {
        combined <- thisTable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ran the code that I posted in my initial post with data.table=TRUE and then the code you suggested, but I keep getting this error message: "Error in get(x) : object 'Participant 1_VP02_Analysis 2_video_20190827_181840_detailed' not found". "Participant 1_VP02 ... is one of the files in my folder. I'd appreciate any further ideas you might have on this one